# How do I move a layout widget with its widgets in PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to move a layout in an application I'm writing.For widgets I use the function move, I tried the following but it didn't work correctly:

Layout code:

```
    self.layoutWidget_3 = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
    self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 346, 158, 32))
    self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget_3"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.setMargin(0)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"))
    self.OK_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.OK_btn.setFont(font)
    self.OK_btn.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.OK_btn.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.OK_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("OK_btn"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.OK_btn)
    self.Cancel_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Times New Roman"))
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.Cancel_btn.setFont(font)
    self.Cancel_btn.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.Cancel_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Cancel_btn"))
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Cancel_btn)
```

Move code

```
#index is an integer
self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 346+5*index, 158, 32))
```

Comment: I do not know about you, but you never use `setLayout` on a widget.why is that?

Comment: Also, `self.cancel_btn` and `self.ok_btn` now should appear above each other, with the latter hiding the former. Is this even working?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setGeometry()` on the widget you want to move, not on the layout.